# Confusion in RNN terminologies?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, rnn

I recently started working on RNN and LSTM and got confused with the terminologies.

What is the meaning of **RNN layer ?**

When I say RNN has 2 layer - does that mean

1. Two RNN cell connected horizontally ?
2. Two RNNs connected vertically. In that case what we call the connection of multiple RNN cell horizontally ?